# How to have stylize and generate effects visible on top of text that is being used for track matte in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, adobe, effects

I am currently using Adobe After Effects 2023 and am having difficulty finding a solution on how to add effects to the text layer that is being used for a track matte.

[image: Setup of my project on After Effects]

I would like for the pattern of "S" (made by an image that gets distorted throughout) to stay, but I would also like to include the effects that are on the other letters that make them a little 2.5D, similar to Photoshop with embossing and lighting. I am now trying to find a way to make it so the text with those effects ("T" and so on) is available on top of the style of the letter "S". Basically, I'd like the solid colors on the other letters to no longer be #EEEEEE but transparent.

I see the eye icon is turned off for the text layer being used for track matte so I assume the effects on it are not visible. The one thing I am starting to work on for another try is making those similar effects that are constant in Adobe Illustrator by checking which opacity would work on top of the colors on "S" and making a gradient mask. Either way, if there is any solution to just using AE for this, that would be lovely.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using layer styles and/or some rasterising video effects, you'll need to pre-comp those layers before applying track mattes to them.